# How do I make a value global so I can access anywhere in a class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How do I make a value global?

For example I have a few lines of code here

```
public class A
{
     int number;

     JLabel[] l = new JLabel[number]; // Problem is at here because the number

     public A( int num )
     {
        number = num;                 // Receive the value from previous file
     }
}
```

Problem is at the line where I state in the commnet.

As far as I know, the number doesn't passed on to creation of `JLabel`. Is there anyway for me to pass the value taken from previous file to the creation of `JLabel`?

I need to create the `JLabel` globally because I need to access it at the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

If I create it inside the method I couldn't access at the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` or is there anyway I could access the `JLabel` I creatd in a method?

Comment: Initialize l in the constructor.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave the top line as `JLabel[] l;` and add `l = new JLabel[number];` in your constructor. The problem is that your code as is will try to access `number` before calling the constructor, so it is not yet set.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your class, you declare **int variable**, which is not initialised, and then you go on to create JLabel array using this variable. To solve this, you can initialize number in your constructor, and also there, create your JLabel, like so:

```
public class A
{
    int number;

    JLabel[] l;

    public A( int num )
    {
        number = num;                 // Receive the value from previous file
        l = new JLabel[number]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there actually any point in retaining `number`?  You already have it as `l.length`.  Also, you might be better off with a (private final?) `List<JLabel> l = new ArrayList<JLabel>();`  (or possibly `List<JLabel> l = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<JLabel>());`)

Comment: Good points Paul, this could have been done without **number**. My code was illustrating why OP had issues and based on their code, how to solve them. Of course there are many ways of doing what he/she wants - this is programming :)

Comment: @Melquiades Thanks for your solution. I wrote the `number` to test something and forgotten to delete off. @Paul so sorry but your solution is too complex for me as I'm just beginner with a little knowledge with Java and JFrame.